# htaccess not redirecting after form submit

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \[location\]\[value\]=(.*?)& [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /version5/category/%1? [NC,L,R=301]
```

I'am making GET form request from the form using GET method, this REGexp works ONLY if its executed from the browser with the matching GET params, but if I do the same from the form GET request, it will not work, can someone tell me why is that?

form:

```
<form method="GET" id="quick_search_form" action="http://localhost/version5/jobs/">
        <div class="location">
            <input value="" class="form-control input-sm" name="keywords[all_words]" id="keywords" placeholder="Keywords" type="text">
        </div>
                    <div class="location">
                <input name="GooglePlace[location][value]" id="GooglePlace" class="form-control form-control__google-location input-sm" value="" placeholder="Location" autocomplete="off" type="text">
<input name="GooglePlace[location][radius]" value="50" id="radius" class="hidden-radius" type="hidden">

            </div>
                <input name="action" value="search" type="hidden">
                    <input name="listing_type[equal]" value="Job" type="hidden">
                <div class="search-right" "="">
            <input value="Search" type="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: We'll need to see your form, maybe it's a error there.

Comment: @Epodax added form

Comment: @Epodax its working fine from the browser, but from this form not, besides they both are sending GET requests, isn't that? so why it doesn't work from the form, I can't understand